# No response with Port.Readline(). Why?

Tags: c#, sockets, serial-port, port

I am using C#. I have a device connected to the com port.
I am sending initial command i.e socket alive to the device through comport .
I already have packet format in hexvalue.
When I write in port i.e

```
port.write(result)
```

I won't get any response in port.readline i.e.

```
port.readline = empty
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: post your complete method.

Comment: *Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it*

Comment: Problem not clearn!? what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make SerialPortDataReceived function and add it to DataRecieved event. After that you should use Read or ReadLine method in this function.

Example :

```
         private SerialPort _serialPort;
    private void InitSerialPort()
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
        {
            Handshake = Handshake.None,

        };

        _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortDataReceived;
        _serialPort.Open();

        return;
    }

   private void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string data = _serialPort.ReadExisting();

    }
```

If Port response to your request you can see "data" value with a breakpoint or something like that

Comment: Thanks for you help and it is resolved.